# Why asp.net core UseEndpoints context.Request.RouteValues["key"] no value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Why asp.net core UseEndpoints context.Request.RouteValues["key"] no value

My Code :

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    var code = $"{context.Request.RouteValues["code"]}";
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(code);
                });
            });
```

[image]

What I expected  :
To get asp.net core UseEndpoints MapGet 's `Key` parameter. e.g :  context.Request.RouteValues["code"] get value 123.

What I've tried & traced :

test1 :
I debug `context.Request.QueryString` is not empty but RouteValues is empty
[image]
[image]

And I read MSDN : `RouteValues = Gets the collection of route values for this request.`

```
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the collection of route values for this request.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The collection of route values for this request.
        public virtual RouteValueDictionary RouteValues
```

test2 :
I can use below code to get code value but it's format is `https://localhost/123` not `https://localhost?code=123`

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/{code:int}", async context =>
                {
                    var code = $"{context.Request.RouteValues["code"]}";
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(code);
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the point not RouteValues it have to use `context.Request.Query`
like below code :

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    var code = context.Request.Query["code"]; //result : 123
             
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(code);
                });
            });
```

RouteValues only for custom mapping url parameter.

and MSDN doc :

```
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the query value collection parsed from Request.QueryString.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The query value collection parsed from Request.QueryString.
        public abstract IQueryCollection Query
          {
               get;
               set;
          }
```